# Whats causing this weird texture stretching on my mesh?

Tags: c#, unity, mesh

Making this mesh via code and the texture seems to only tile on the sides, but not on the top. Any idea whats going on?

[image]
[image]

```
public class CoreMeshCreator : MonoBehaviour 
{
//Initialization
public void Start()
{
    MeshFilter meshFilter = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    MeshCollider meshCollider = this.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    meshFilter.mesh = Generate();
    meshCollider.sharedMesh = meshFilter.mesh;
}

public Mesh Generate()
{
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    float sqrt = (Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2);

    Vector3 v0 = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
    Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(-4, -1, 0);
    Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(-5, -1, sqrt * 2);
    Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(-4, -1, sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v4 = new Vector3(-2, -1, sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v5 = new Vector3(-1, -1, sqrt * 6);
    Vector3 v6 = new Vector3(1, -1, sqrt * 6);
    Vector3 v7 = new Vector3(2, -1, sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v8 = new Vector3(4, -1, sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v9 = new Vector3(5, -1, sqrt * 2);
    Vector3 v10 = new Vector3(4, -1, 0);
    Vector3 v11 = new Vector3(5, -1, -sqrt * 2);
    Vector3 v12 = new Vector3(4, -1, -sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v13 = new Vector3(2, -1, -sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v14 = new Vector3(1, -1, -sqrt * 6);
    Vector3 v15 = new Vector3(-1, -1, -sqrt * 6);
    Vector3 v16 = new Vector3(-2, -1, -sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v17 = new Vector3(-4, -1, -sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v18 = new Vector3(-5, -1, -sqrt * 2);
    Vector3 v19 = new Vector3(-4, 1, 0);
    Vector3 v20 = new Vector3(-5, 1, sqrt*2);
    Vector3 v21 = new Vector3(-4, 1, sqrt*4);
    Vector3 v22 = new Vector3(-2, 1, sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v23 = new Vector3(-1, 1, sqrt * 6);
    Vector3 v24 = new Vector3(1, 1, sqrt * 6);
    Vector3 v25 = new Vector3(2, 1, sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v26 = new Vector3(4, 1, sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v27 = new Vector3(5, 1, sqrt * 2);
    Vector3 v28 = new Vector3(4, 1, 0);
    Vector3 v29 = new Vector3(5, 1, -sqrt * 2);
    Vector3 v30 = new Vector3(4, 1, -sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v31 = new Vector3(2, 1, -sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v32 = new Vector3(1, 1, -sqrt * 6);
    Vector3 v33 = new Vector3(-1, 1, -sqrt * 6);
    Vector3 v34 = new Vector3(-2, 1, -sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v35 = new Vector3(-4, 1, -sqrt * 4);
    Vector3 v36 = new Vector3(-5, 1, -sqrt * 2);
    Vector3 v37 = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

    mesh.vertices = new Vector3[] 
    {
        v0,
        v1, v2,
        v3, v4,
        v5, v6,
        v7, v8,
        v9, v10,
        v11, v12,
        v13, v14,
        v15, v16,
        v17, v18,
        v19, v20,
        v21, v22,
        v23, v24, 
        v25, v26,
        v27, v28, 
        v29, v30,
        v31, v32, 
        v33, v34, 
        v35, v36, 
        v37,
    };

    mesh.triangles = new int[] 
    {
        //top
        1,0,2,
        2,0,3,
        3,0,4,
        4,0,5,
        5,0,6,
        6,0,7,
        7,0,8,
        8,0,9,
        9,0,10,
        10,0,11,
        11,0,12,
        12,0,13,
        13,0,14,
        14,0,15,
        15,0,16,
        16,0,17,
        17,0,18,
        18,0,1,
        //Bottom
        20,37,19,
        21,37,20,
        22,37,21,
        23,37,22,
        24,37,23,
        25,37,24,
        26,37,25,
        27,37,26,
        28,37,27,
        29,37,28,
        30,37,29,
        31,37,30,
        32,37,31,
        33,37,32,
        34,37,33,
        35,37,34,
        36,37,35,
        19,37,36,
        //Sides
        23,5,6,
        23,6,24,
        24,6,7,
        24,7,25,
        25,7,8,
        25,8,26,
        26,8,9,
        26,9,27,
        9,10,27,
        27,10,28,
        28,10,11,
        28,11,29,
        11,12,29,
        12,30,29,
        13,30,12,
        30,13,31,
        31,13,14,
        31,14,32,
        15,32,14,
        15,33,32,
        33,15,16,
        33,16,34,
        34,16,17,
        34,17,35,
        17,18,35,
        35,18,36,
        18,1,36,
        36,1,19,
        19,1,2,
        19,2,20,
        20,2,3,
        20,3,21,
        21,3,4,
        21,4,22,
        22,4,5,
        22,5,23
    };

    mesh.RecalculateNormals();

    return mesh;
}

}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere you are specifying texture coordinates for your mesh. It looks like they're being taken from your x and y positions, so naturally there's no tiling in the z direction. (It only shows on the top because the top is the only surface perpendicular to both x and y.) Can't help with how to set them properly in Unity, sorry.

Comment: As Kevin said, you are most likely not specifying your UVs correctly. It seems as though the x and y coordinates are used for your UVs. Therefore, fragments with the same x and y coordinates will get assigned the same part of the texture. Maybe see if you can find a UV unwrap option in Unity (eg. using a box projection or a cylindrical projection).

Answer (score 2):

As others above have said, you need to generate texture coordinates for the top of your object. You can do it by hand (i.e. have your artist do it in their 3D software), or you can do it algorithmically.

I've had good success using tri-planar mapping. There's a good explanation [here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/use-tri-planar-texture-mapping-for-better-terrain--gamedev-13821). Essentially, you take the x, y, and z components of the normal and use them as weights for blending 3 values together. Those values are samples of your texture using xy, yz, and xz coordinates.